# BULK INSERT from shared drive using sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a little query that I want to bulk import from a shared network drive:

```
BULK INSERT 
    test
FROM 
    '\\fullpath\path\file.csv' 
WITH 
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

This doesn't work and gives this error:

```
Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)
```

From what I've read, this is because the shared drive doesn't recognize the SQL Server user (me) because the authentications are different.

Would I be better off putting these files on the SQL Server itself, or granting some kind of permission on the shared drive?  I'm not sure what to tell our IT group to do in terms of allowing SQL Server to "see" the shared drive.

Alternatively, I'm not sure how to access the SQL Server directory directly to place the CSV files.  What do you all think?

Comment: While it's possible in principle, in practice I've found it difficult to get SQL to bcp from a remote machine, whether using UNC or mapped drives.  If copying it locally is an option, I'd just do that.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Not yet, but they are looking into it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at the SQL Server NT service on the server that hosts the SQL instance.  Find out what account the NT service is running under (it could be an account that is local to the server, or a domain/AD account).  **That** is the account that needs access to `\\fullpath\path\`, not the account you use to make your connection to the SQL instance.